# Using delete on std::vector::back() before pop_back(), and using std::move() for new element

Tags: c++, stdvector, delete-operator

I have this function, but I'm not sure why I need to use
`delete m_gameStates.back()` before using `m_gameStates.pop_back()` when I know that `pop_back()` destroys the element.

```
 //in header :
     std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameState>> m_gameStates;
... 
...

void GameStateMechine::changeState(std::unique_ptr<GameState> pState)
{
    if(!m_gameStates.empty())
    {
        if(m_gameStates.back()->getStateID() == pState->getStateID())
        {
            return;
        }
        if(m_gameStates.back()->onExit())
        {
            delete m_gameStates.back();
            m_gameStates.pop_back();
        }
        m_gameStates.push_back(std::move(pState));
        m_gameStates.back()->onEnter();
    }
}
```

Is the `delete` operation unnecessary?

Also, for complex objects, is using `std::move()` (and not copy) the right thing to do
always?

For example:

```
m_gameStates.push_back(std::move(pState));
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I have a lot of problems with using `std::unique_ptr` in `std::vector`. If I remove it and use raw pointers in the `std::vector`, do I need still to `delete` it?

Comment: It's not just unnecessary, I'm surprised if it compiles, the whole point of `unique_ptr` is that you don't need to use `delete`. If this code does compile you will be deleting things twice

Comment: You might get `use of deleted function of std::unique_ptr` if  `push_back()` is not supplied with a moveable unique pointer.

Comment: If you actually want to delete the contents of a `std::unique_ptr` before ts lifetime ends, you call `.reset()` on it. But that’s rarely necessary.

Comment: yep, it doesn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/qbYxv418v please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles i have allot of problem with the uniqu_ptr in vector , 
what about if i remove it and use raw pointers in the std::vector do i need still delete it ?

Comment: that depends on who owns that data? using `unique_ptr` in the vector is probably the correct approach, avoid using raw pointers and `delete` wherever possible. Only use raw pointers if someone else owns the memory and you just want a reference to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `unique_ptr` is to have one and only one owner for `pointer` and when its owner destroyed `unique_ptr` will delete `pointer` too. When you call `m_gameStates.pop_back()` it destroys last element that in turn is the owner of `unique_ptr`. Hence `delete m_gameStates.back()` not necessary and should not even compile.

Your `std::unique_ptr<GameState> pState` argument belongs to function. If not `std::move` in `m_gameStates.push_back(std::move(pState))` `pState` will be deleted at function's end so you moved its ownership to `vector` and that's correct.

If you use raw pointer you must deleted it when you don't need it and remember not to use it after `delete`. If `GameState` instance owned at same time by only one owner `std::move` along with `std::unique_ptr` will be good idea. If you want `GameState` instance to be shared by multiple  owners use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: i accepted you answer but just to let you know that i coulnt manage to use it in the end 
I mean the unique_ptr , and moved back to raw pointer see this question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75719158/unique-ptr-h106530-error-no-matching-function-for-call-to?noredirect=1#comment133576165_75719158